# Rails with PostgreSQL hstore query way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I use PostgreSQL feature hstore in my rails app, recently I add gin index to speedup my query from hstore.

```
add_index :articles, :published_at_translations, using: :gin
```

I surveyed some articles, like [this](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore) mentioned:

**"@>"** is at least twice as fast (using indexes)

and my data column is like:

> published_at_translations[
>   "en"=>"2016-05-17T10:36:06","cn"=>"2016-05-17T10:36:06"]

old query:

```
scope :now_published, -> { where("published_at_translations -> ? <= ? and state_translations -> ? = ?", I18n.locale, DateTime.current, I18n.locale, :published ) }
```

new:

```
scope :now_published, -> { where("published_at_translations -> ? <= ? and state_translations @> '#{I18n.locale}=>#{:published}'", I18n.locale, DateTime.current ) }
```

but I cat't add condition like >= or <= ... etc with **"@>"**, how can I refactor my query with **"@>"** or other way to get speedup efficiency from gin index?

Comment: have you looked at the actualy hstore docs on this?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/hstore.html  It is worth reading in detail to find the exact one that you need.

Comment: I didn't get what I want in this docs... did I miss something?